# Multiple inputs for function

Tags: ios, objective-c, function

I have a function as shown below and at the moment i pass one variable to it `SearchTerm` i wish to pass another variable to it (another string) how do i do it?

```
- (void)GetYoutube:(NSString *) SearchTerm {

}
```

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, I suggest you have a read of some of the docs first and then google the basics. Probably faster than asking on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below :

```
(void)GetYoutube:(NSString *) SearchTerm withOtherString:(NSString*) myOtherString{

}
```

Would suggest you to go throught the basic of obj-C...

Thanks

Comment: First app :P trying to get there

Comment: And how would i call the function

Comment: [myObj GetYoutube:searchstring withOtherString:myOtherString];

Comment: I suggest you read and act on the most important part of his answer: "Would suggest you to go throught the basic of obj-C..."

Answer (score 0):

- (void)GetYoutube:(NSString *) SearchTerm AnotherTerm:(NSString*) SearchTerm2
  {

}